# Splitting one graph in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm very new to R programming. Is there any way for me to split one graph into two or more (in range)? Example, I would like to take one part of the graph from point 0.0-0.4. The graph that I would like to split is the multiple regression graph. My code for linear multiple regression are as below.

```
lmThpTraffic=lm(Total.DL.Traffic.Volume~Avg.DL.User.THP, data=first)
summary(lmThpTraffic)
plot(lmThpTraffic)
```

Comment: Is `plot(lmThpTraffic, xlim = c(0, 0.4))` what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me.